# How to change sticky behavior when responsive with bootstrap-4

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4, responsive, sticky

I use angular with bootstrap for my project.
I have a header, which consists of tow parts, and a content area. When the resolution is small the header wraps.

[Header and content on large screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4uqC.png)

[Header and content on small screens, wrapped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCyto.png)

```
<div class="sticky row">
  <div class="col-md-7" style="height: 50px; background-color: seagreen;">
    Header A
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5" style="height: 50px; background-color: skyblue;">
    Header B
  </div>
</div>
<div style="height: 1500px; width: 100%; background-color: slategray;">
  any content<br />
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
  eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
  voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita
  kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</div>
```

I also made the header sticky, so that my content flows beneath the header.

```
.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
}
```

This works fine as you can see in this Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-responsive-sticky

But for the small screend I want the **Header B also to scroll beneath Header A** and not be sticky.
As Header A and Header B are in one div I don't know if there is any way to do this, when at the same time, I want to keep the wrapping of the header.

Thanks for any ideas :)

Comment: You can achieve this without grid in the header. Instead of row and two cols, just use two inline block divs.

Comment: Thanks Arcteezy, I tried it. The problem is, that with inline-block after wrapping the div is not filling the whole width; In my case I have a 60% and a 40% div; with the left one min-width: 800px; for braking. This leaves the rest empty: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbJlG.png

Comment: You can set the width to 100% for mobile devices. BTW below is a fine solution but has duplicate code. If that's a problem, I can give the solution with inline divs.

Comment: Hmm, how do I do that? I set the width do 60 and 40 as I mentioned above. A solution without duplicate code would be more elegant :) Can you post it as an answer?

Comment: See if the below answer suits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have taken the header ratio to be 6:4 for large screens. The first division will be sticky by default and the second div will be sticky only for large screens.

**HTML :**

```
<div class="custom-col-6 sticky" style="height: 50px; background-color: seagreen;">
  Header A
</div>
<div class="custom-col-4" style="height: 50px; background-color: skyblue;">
  Header B
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
.custom-col-4,
.custom-col-6 {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .custom-col-6 {
    width: 60%;
  }
  .custom-col-4 {
    width: 40%;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

Demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-responsive-sticky-2aprb3?file=src/app/app.component.css

Comment: Not having a surrounding div in the header caused me a little trouble, because in real-life I have not a fixed height (as intended in the example) for both header divs, but one relies on the other. But not having redundant code is more elegant and I will solve height issue either with fixed value, or dynamic height change. Not decided yet :) THX

Answer (score 0):

You can hide/show div using bootstrap 4 grid property. Please check below code:

```
<div class="sticky row">
  <div class="col-md-7" style="height: 50px; background-color: seagreen;">
    Header A
  </div>
  <div class="d-none d-md-block col-md-5" style="height: 50px; background-color: skyblue;">
    Header B
  </div>
</div>
 <div class="d-block d-md-none" style="height: 50px; background-color: skyblue;">
    Header B
  </div>
<div style="height: 1500px; width: 100%; background-color: slategray;">
  any content<br />
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
  eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
  voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita
  kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</div>
```

Comment: if you need a surrounding div for both header elements, e.g. to have the same dynamic height, this is the answer I recommend. if you can set fixed height, see accepted answer.